# conversion to pdflatex loses all figures

Tags: pdftex, dvi

I am trying to compile a document using pdflatex but I lose all figures (they look blank). The document was created by using the TeX + DVI typeset, and now I'm trying to change this to Pdftex. Is there a simple way to get around this issue? Can I just add something to the document so that Pdftex converts the eps figures I have on the fly?

I tried converting the figures myself using `epstopdf`, but there are some figures where there is some superimposed text and this approach doesn't work, for example:

```
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{picture}(8,6)(0.0,-0.5)
%\includegraphics[width=8cm]{cont_equi}
\put(0.3,-0.3){\psfig{figure=figures/cont_equi.eps,width=8cm}}
\put(0,2.8){$\sigma_{11}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$}
\put(6.7,2.8){$\sigma_{11}$\footnotesize$(x_1+dx_1,x_2,x_3)$}
\put(3.3,2.2){$\sigma_{12}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$}
\put(3.8,3.3){$\sigma_{12}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2+dx_2,x_3)$}
\put(4.2,4.3){$\sigma_{13}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2,x_3+dx_3)$}
\put(3.2,0.9){$\sigma_{13}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$}
\put(-0.4,1.5){$x_3$}
\put(1.6,-0.1){$x_1$}
\put(1.,1.1){$x_2$}
\put(3.6,-0.5){$dx_1$}
\put(8.4,3.7){$dx_3$}
\put(7.2,1){$dx_2$}
\end{picture}
\end{center}
\caption{Equilibrium in a continuous systems}
\label{fig:cont_equi}
\end{figure}
```

In the code above, uncommenting the `includegraphics` statement and commenting the next line shifts all manually added equations to the right.

Comment: Add `usepackage{epstopdf}` and compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape file`

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Have you tried that already? What errors do you get?

Comment: I put on the preamble `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and the document compiles, but I don't see the figures being converted. All the eps figures look blank.

Comment: Did you put it *after* `\usepackage{graphicx}` and have enabled `--shell-escape` option?

Comment: I put it after the first line `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{book}`. I don't know how to enable that option though.

Comment: @aaragon: The `--shell-escape` option is designed for the commandline, i.e. `pdfdlatex --shell-escape`. Do you have `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` in your document?

Comment: I'm using TeXShop (Mac app), so I changed the command line to `pdflatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1` but still nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

`\includegraphics` should be put inside `\put` as `\psfig`. Otherwise the following `\put` commands are moved to the right by the width of the `\includegraphics` statement. Also the translation of the `\put` command for `\psfig` would be lost.

```
\begin{picture}(8,6)(0.0,-0.5)
  \put(0.3,-0.3){\includgraphics[width=8cm]{cont_equi}}
  \put(0,2.8){$\sigma_{11}$\footnotesize$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$}
  ...

\end{picture}
```

Comment: That solved the problem that the figure is moving to the right, but still I can't seem to convert automatically those eps figures to pdf on the fly.

Comment: @aaragon With a modern TeX distribution the conversion should work on the fly. Otherwise the shell-escape/write18 feature needs to be enabled and package `epstopdf` to be loaded (if it is not done automatically by `graphics.cfg`).